# List Template showing the wrong image

Tags: list-definition, list-template, file-icons

I've created a list definition from a content type in Visual Studio 2010 for SharePoint 2010. They are based off a custom list. When I deploy locally, I see the correct image in View All Site Content for these lists, `/_layouts/images/itgen.png.`

When I package this and deploy it on our staging environment, the icons are messed up, they are somehow being swapped with PowerPivot icons. I'm a bit perplexed as to how this is happening, relatively minor, but visually annoying. Here is the list template where it is defined but once packaged and deployed, does not have the right icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ListTemplate
        Name="Flag"
        Type="10002"
        BaseType="0"
        OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="410"
        DisplayName="Flag"
        NoCrawl="TRUE"
        Hidden="TRUE"
        Category="Custom Lists"
        Description="Flagging List Definition"
        Image="/_layouts/images/itgen.png"/>
</Elements>
```

Anywhere else I can track this down?

Here are a couple of screenshots, this is my dev environment where my cutoms lists show the correct image in the View All Site Content page.
[image]

And this is wht View All Site Content looks like when this is packaged and deployed as a feature. Both of these are custom lists and should be displaying the custom list icon, not powerpivot icons.
[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what image *is* getting loaded if you look at the network activity in the developer tools?

Comment: I'll have to check in the morning, View source on the images shows it is the power pivot images for 2 of the 3 lists I provisioned this way.

Comment: I see Gets for the wrong images, atomsvc_32_96.png and powerpivot_32_32.png, so I'm not sure where this is getting messed up.

Comment: could you please check couple of things? 1) whats the location of images you are seeing? 2) are you images deployed to correct location /_layouts/images/ 3) did you see other than you custom image in the images folder. I am wondering may be your images not deployed into the folder which causing this issue.

Comment: I'm seeing icons from the _layouts/images/PowerPivot/ directory. I'm not deploying any images with the list, I'm telling it to use the default image for a custom list.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of the correct and wrong images?

Comment: Sure, I'll add them in the morning, I don't have access at the moment.

Comment: Screenshots added.

Comment: Thinking aloud: are you sure there aren't some other conflicting templates around? Does all the rest of the template structure match???

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: nope, i havent a clue why this is happening and havent figured where it is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have resolved it but it didn't have anything to do with any of the code I created. I needed to redeploy the feature and I looked over the existing featres on the site. I disabled the PowerPivot Feature Integration for Site Collections feature and my custom lists that get created in my feature show the correct icons now.

I don't know why that would make the icons change but it did.